# What plants are these

Tags: botany

[image]

These are aquatic plants. Anyone knows the name please? Well. For a week more and most of them stems rotted. So, wondering if its planted by submerged in the soil or what.

Comment: I notice you've neon tetras indicating a tropical temperature, are the plants especially meant for that or just any random plants?

Comment: i have no idea either since the seller just gave random plants different than what I ordered. I wanna know how to care for these.

Answer (score 1):

Take these with a grain of salt, as it is quite difficult to tell from a single, far-away, picture, and I am no expert on aquaria or aquarium plants.

The narrow-leaved ([lanceolate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lanceolate)) one appears to be *Pogostemon*, possibly the species * [stellatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogostemon_stellatus)*, though I think this should (under optimal conditions) have red stems and upper leaves. This seems to have strict requirements for growth of added CO<sub>2</sub> and intense light.

I found a site [Tropica.com](https://tropica.com) (I have no affiliation with, nor is this an endorsement of, the company) that sells a lot of aquarium plants and has good listings of the conditions needed for growth, along with pictures and descriptions, so it might be worth a browse through there to see if something fits better.

The second, broad-leaved with toothed margins, plant might be *[Erythranthe guttata](https://www.wnps.org/native-plant-directory/168:erythranthe-guttata)* (Monkey Musk), which is a common (sometimes invasive) plant of stream margins, but I don't know how well it will grow fully submerged. It will certainly tolerate short submergings (a few days), but as an aquarium plant??